# Is power dissipation constant for a given mass of copper generating a given magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, magnetic-flux

What I mean, is that for a given field and a given mass of copper coil, power dissipation is independent of the form of that copper, whether thick wires or thin.

Is it true?

Comment: What do you mean "form"? Field where? It could be a tangled mess that produces no net field at a distance, for example. If you mean for the same general geometry (fields and current densities), it doesn't matter how it's divided, e.g. one or many turns in a winding of the same overall size and shape.

Comment: @TimWilliams Fixed it - the form is a coil

Comment: Do you mean how 1000 turns and 1 amp might as well be one big conductor carrying 1000 amps?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, for the same mass of copper

Comment: DC or high frequency AC?

Comment: @Andyaka Low enough frequency that skin effect can be ignored

Answer (score 1):

> power dissipation is independent of the form of that copper, whether thick wires or thin.
>
> Is it true?

Yes.

You only need to do a simple thought experiment of two windings on the same electromagnet former, each taking \$V\$ volts and \$I\$ amps.

Connect them in series and they take \$2VI\$ power. Connect them in parallel, and they are equivalent to a single winding of twice the area, and take \$2VI\$ power.

Replace 2 by N in the above argument to generalise it to any number of turns of any thickness wire, but while having the same total mass, power dissipation, and magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

\$N\$ closely spaced wires, each having a cross section \$A\$, and a current \$I\$, will produce a magnetic field approximately equal to a single wire having a cross section \$N \cdot A\$ and a current of \$N \cdot I\$.

At higher frequencies, the single wire will have greater resistance than multiple wires, due to the skin-effect. [Litz wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire) is a multi-strand wire used to counter-act skin-effect resistance.

The "copper efficiency" of an air-core inductor depends upon the winding geometry. A [Brooks coil](http://www.nessengr.com/technical-data/brooks-coil-and-calculator/) is the geometry that will produce the greatest magnetic field for the least mass of copper.

The "copper efficiency" of an inductor or electromagnet with an iron or ferrite core depends less on the winding geometry than an equivalent air core inductor.

Comment: Thanks - not heard of a Brooks coil until now